# Compare two datatables to see which fields have been changed

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview

I am trying to compare two datatables, each datatable will hold a snapshot of a parts list at a point in time. So for example DT1 will show the parts as they were on the 31/3 and DT2 will show as they are on the 15/04. This will eventually need to highlight a datagridview (green is new record, red is deleted record, yellow is changed cell)

I can do (and have) this with nested for next loops but it is slow to process 1000 records.
I am presently adding a dummy field to each row in the parts list "NAAANNAA" where 'N' is field not changed and 'A' is field amended between the two DTs. 'I' for inserted and 'D' for deleted.
The paint method on the cell just has style.backcolor=color.yellow where string.instr(dgv.currentcell.columnindex)="A" (air code, not need pc at the moment)

Is there an easier way to do with Linq?

App is VB in VS2010 but soon to be either VB or C# in VS2019. Winforms with a SQL backend.

From memory elsewhere in the code it does the nested for next loops, this is just the cellformatting 
--> Updated with some code

```
Private Sub dgvDOIssue_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvDOIssue.CellFormatting
    Dim changed_flags As String = ""

    Try
        If UcDOCompare1.DataGridView1.Rows.Count >= e.RowIndex Then
            With UcDOCompare1.DataGridView1

                changed_flags = .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(.Columns.Count - 1).Value
                If Strings.Mid(changed_flags, e.ColumnIndex + 1, 1) = "I" Then
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
                ElseIf Strings.Mid(changed_flags, e.ColumnIndex + 1, 1) = "A" Then
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                ElseIf Strings.Mid(changed_flags, e.ColumnIndex + 1, 1) = "G" Then
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink
                Else
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
                End If

            End With
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

End sub

Comment: Could you show us your current comparison code and datasource types/structures?  Assuming you've got 8 fields in your datasets, 8000 comparisons is probably not a huge amount so shouldn't be overly slow.  How often does this comparison need to be run?  Does it need to be live, if so, might be better to just compare current rows rather than iterate the entire datasets

Comment: There are approximately 1000 rows per revision and approximately 100 columns per row. The application replaces Excel spreadsheets. The system stores every revision while the job is going through the works.

Comment: So what is making the data changes.  User or some event behind the scenes?  If it's a user, might be more efficient to do the highlighting on just the current row.

Comment: Could also be more efficient to do you're compare on the underlying datasource rather than via the UI components

Comment: There is a stored procedure that creates the changed_flags in the first instance but the user then amends in the DGV. As they move entries around it will need to highlight.

Comment: Well assuming then there are no changes at the time the stored procedure runs, that would mean that the only time the data changes is due to user entry.  So from that I would say you could use something like the CellValueChanged, UserAddedRow and UserDeletedRow events on the DataGridView objects to trap the individual edits and update the current row highlights saving you from going through the entire datasets

Comment: The [DataRow Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=netframework-4.8) implements version information. Tracking changes to the individual field level is possible by comparing either the Current or Proposed row version against the Original version.  I have used this in the past to highlight changes.

Comment: "There is a stored procedure that creates the changed_flags in the first instance" - does this mean that original basis table is retrieved and then compared to the current table to produce your flags that are appended to the current rows?  If so, you could do the same in your code merging the current table into the original to get the DataTable to track the changes without the use of the flags.